# rules for min value not working with jquery validate

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-validate

I have this validation code, which looks to work ok when I put text in number field, but when I put value below 1, which is set in rules as min, no message appears even it should

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('#payment_amount').validate({
        lang: 'sk',
        rules: {
          "payment[amount]": {
            required: true,
            min: 1,
            max: 9999999 
          }
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
          $(element).parent().addClass('state-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
          $(element).parent().removeClass('state-error');
        }
      });
    });
```

When I use same code on different page with input type number, checking for min value works

this is how I create my input field

```
<%= f.number_field :amount, :style=>"-moz-appearance:textfield;", :required=> true %>
```

and this is html

```
<input type="number" id="payment_amount" name="payment[amount]" required="required" style="-moz-appearance:textfield;" aria-required="true" novalidate="novalidate" aria-invalid="false">
```

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I've found a solution
don't know why but even standard validation is working on #element, min value works only when I use form as element, not #input field

```
$('form').validate({
    lang: 'sk',
    rules: {
      'payment[amount]': {
        min: 1
      }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).parent().addClass('state-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element).parent().removeClass('state-error');
    }
  });
```

Comment: You attach the `.validate()` method to the `form` element to initialize the plugin on your form; that's why each field `name` is specified within the `rules` object.

Answer (score 0):

You've attached the `.validate()` method to your input field with `id="payment_amount"`...

```
$('#payment_amount').validate({
    lang: 'sk',
    rules: {
      "payment[amount]": {
      ...
```

However, you are supposed to attach the `.validate()` method to the `form` element to *initialize* the plugin on your form; that's why each field `name` is specified within the `rules` object.

```
$('#my_form_id').validate({ // <- attach to the form; these are the options for this form
    lang: 'sk',
    rules: {
      "payment[amount]": { // <- the field name is specified here
      ...
```